# How to organize webforms on (admin/content/webform) into groups

Tags: taxonomy-terms, webforms, views, nodes

**Goal**: I want to be able to organize the list of webforms on the admin/content/webform page, which is in a View to my understanding, in groups. Either via visual groups (using some header or box) or add a filter to the page so that I can specifically look up a term ID that is associated with one or multiple webforms (like you can on the admin/content page).

So for example: if I had several webforms about housing, I would like to be able to create the header 'Housing' and have associated webforms underneath. Or be able to select the Vocab or TID associated with one or multiple webforms and filter the results.

I'm a very new user to Drupal (couple months experience on the job only). I've spent the last ~4 days searching the internet to find info to help me and have found some promising things but haven't gotten anything to work. Many things are over my head.

The best two things I've tried are the following:

**1)** I've tried editing the Webform View. I've tried adding a TID field but that's not listed as an option to add. My plan was to add a Contextual Filter for TIDs.

**2)** I've tried adding a Term Reference field and Node Reference field to a Webform. This seemed promising until I realized they became Select List options on the actual webform presented to the user. Obviously this will not do what I want to do on the developer side of things.

I've heard about creating custom admin pages with views but I was hoping for a simpler way to accomplish this. If that is the only way to do so, so be it.

I'm using Webforms 7.x-4.4 fyi.

Thanks for any help! Sorry this is long and probably newbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question.

Ended up creating a new Administration View of type content for only webforms. I then added the field 'Content: Term Group' which I added to the Webform Content type which is a term reference. I should mention I already created a new Taxonomy Vocabulary and gave that vocabulary three children taxonomy terms. From then it was as simple as noticing that 'Term reference' showed up when I hit Edit on a specific Webform so I can select one of the taxonomies. Then I changed the Format Setting 'Grouping field Nr.1' to 'Term Group' and thats it! Now my custom link (/admin/content/webform-groups) page shows all the webforms separated into separate boxes with their respective Term ID name above.